# Allow specific ports and restrict other ports to be view for other computer in a same LAN

Tags: apache, server, httpd.conf

**I'm wondering if this can be done:**

I'm letting my friends to view my project by using my computer name. For example

```
http://mycomputername:1003/
```

**Note:**

I have a lot of projects and I configured it on different ports. E.g:

```
http://mycomputername:1001/  //Project 1  [Only can be view in my local]
http://mycomputername:1002/  //Project 2  [Only can be view in my local]
http://mycomputername:1003/  //Project 3  [Only this project I need to allow on my friends]
http://mycomputername:1005/  //Project 4  [Only can be view in my local]
```

How I can do that? Use `httpd.conf` or what? Currently I use `xampp` for my localserver.

**Extra notes:**

I'm using something like this to assign my project to specific port in `httpd.conf`

```
# Project 1
Listen 1001
<VirtualHost *:1001>
     DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/project1/"
</VirtualHost>


# Project 2
Listen 1002
<VirtualHost *:1002>
     DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/project2/"
</VirtualHost>

...
```

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Comment: Oh..so I need to write on Server Fault site?

Comment: yea or flag and a mod can migrate it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add servername in your configuration:

```
# Project 1
Listen 1001
<VirtualHost *:1001>
     ServerName mycomputername
     DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/project1/"
</VirtualHost>


# Project 2
Listen 1002
<VirtualHost *:1002>
     ServerName mycomputername
     DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/project2/"
</VirtualHost>
```

And check your firewall to not block thoose ports